# unit testing covering the branch case

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying write unit test for below .js using mocha

```
const fs = require('fs')
const defaultValue = 255

const envValue = process.env.Var1Value
const valueToUse = envValue && !isNaN(envValue) ? parseInt(envValue) : defaultValue

module.exports.MyFun = () => {
  //use the value of 'valueToUse'
}
```

In my unit testing, I am trying to cover the cases for "valueToUse" both from environment and from default value.
I trying to understand how can cover both the scenarios for unit testing. If I set the process.env.Var1Value before loading the module (using require) it covers the first scenario, but not the other case and in reverse if I don't set the env variable it cover the other case, as the module is being loaded only once... how shall I have an unit test that covers both the scenario?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to import you module into your test function (using require) and setting the Var1Value before the import ? like this:
process.env.Var1Value = '1';
const myFunc = require('./myModule.js');
// later
process.env.Var1Value = undefined;
const myFunc = require('./myModule.js');

Comment: Does `valueToUse` have to be evaluated immediately? This would be much easier to test if it was moved into a helper function or directly into `MyFun`.

Comment: @Kornflexx - I tried that option, it does not work as the module gets loaded only once and looks like the second require skips the loading

Comment: @Jake, I didn't want to do that because MyFun will be called multiple times and the value of  'valueToUse' does not change after loading the module.This will be a unnecessary calculation!

Comment: Do you want testable code? Or to save picoseconds on a function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your current startup code truly has to be calculated at startup.  Then you will be left with some solution where the executable is started several times, for example from a shell script.  Which of the tests to be executed could then be communicated to the test's `main` function via some command line arguments.  This is possible, but typically it is not necessary to do it like this.

An alternative option is to turn the startup code into something that can be re-executed under the control of the test code - for example, in form of some `init()` function that computes the values of the global/static variables.  For the startup of the production code this does not have a big performance impact, and in the production code the `init()` function will really only be computed once.  For the run-time performance there is no penalty at all.  For unit-testing however this brings the advantage that you can call `init()` as often as you like.

You can go further and wrap the computation of `valueToUse` into a function of its own, such that this function is called by `init()` to set the value of `valueToUse`. The nice point is that then this function also can be tested individually by unit-testing.  Again, only a slight performance penalty during startup, but not during execution.

Admittedly, all these are tradeoffs: You also can not classify the variables as const etc.  However, that is why there is a concept called "design for testability": Because testable code sometimes looks different from code that has not been designed for testability.